# Pull N commits from another remote that's not up-to-date

Tags: git, version-control, github

Here's detailed information to demonstrate the issue:

1. Person A forks my project
2. Person A commits stuff to his fork (8 commits++)
3. Person A forgets to pull upstream changes
4. Person A commits other stuff to his fork (4 commits)

What I want to do is:
Pull the last 4 commits (see point 4) from him only. I heard `git cherry-pick` is the command for this but I have no clue how would I do this if there are too many conflicts to solve and I don't even want to pull every single commit he has done.

Stuff I've already tried:

1. Pull all of his stuff in another branch
2. Try some cherry-pick commands (And ofcourse noone worked since there are a lot of conflicts etc.)
3. git fetch and try cherry-pick (No luck as well).

Considering I have:
His remote URL stored and a branch for his stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a range cherry-pick:

```
 git cherry-pick his-remote/branch-name~4..his-remote/branch-name
```

or use rebase:

```
 git rebase --onto your-branch his-remote/branch-name~4 his-remote/branch-name
```

There is no avoiding the conflicts. You need to resolve them. If you're on windows, Beyond Compare or P4Merge are the 2 that can help a lot with tricky conflict resolutions.

Depending on how many changes were done on your side, you may want to reset back to the common point, fast-forward merge his changes and rebase your changes on top of that as you are more familiar with what you have done in your commits and that could potentially make the conflict resolutions much easier.